# Traveling by Greyhound?

Tags: usa, luggage, buses, greyhound

I'm just wanting to ask a few questions about [Greyhound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greyhound_Lines). My sister and I are traveling from Austin, TX to Eugene, OR this Tuesday. I've never traveled by Greyhound before, and I'm very, very nervous. There are a couple of things worrying me. One is that our tickets were purchased online by our uncle, and he accidentally selected print-at-home tickets. They require photo ID, but my sister is under eighteen, and doesn't have anything. (I don't even know how to get her birth certificate, especially with just two days.)  I'm eighteen, and have photo ID, so I'm hoping they will let us both board. I emailed the webmasters about this, and got several responses that we would be fine. I'm just worried that the actual people at the stations will disagree with this, as I've heard that Greyhound can be.... difficult. We also have three transfers, so I'm worried about each station having a problem... Another thing is that, I've read online that some buses will get stopped by police, to check for things like drugs, or legal immigration status. Like I said, she doesn't have ID, so I'm very worried about this.

Other than that, I just have some basic questions. I'm wondering about what I do when I get there, as far as checking bags, and finding my bus, etc. Is Greyhound really as bad as people say it is? We have a lot of luggage, which we've narrowed down to two carry-ons, a duffel bag and a box to be checked for free, and a guitar case and box with an amp in it, to be checked for a total of twenty dollars. If I'm right, it should only cost me twenty dollars to check those two extra bags, right?

One last thing. When buying the tickets online, we selected the route that had a little symbol that said 'express reservation'. Is this the same as the express routes, with power outlets, wifi, extra legroom, etc? Just wondering...

Comment: ¿How did it go?

Answer (score 5):

You should be checking [Greyhound's website for policies related to travel](http://www.greyhound.com/en/ticketsandtravel/default.aspx).  For example depending how old your sister is she may be falling under the [Children Travelling](http://www.greyhound.com/en/ticketsandtravel/childrentraveling.aspx) policy.  Normally if she is a resident of Texas and over 15 years old she can have a [driver's license](http://www.txdps.state.tx.us/DriverLicense/teenDriver.htm), which is an ID if not according to policy she has to be accompanied by you and it would be fine.  The only thing that may be required is that she has a letter from your parents that she is allowed to travel with you, while this is a definite requirement for out of country travel without both parents this may be a requirement from your state (see Illinois exception for Greyhound's Children policy).

As far as the baggage is concerned if I understand it correctly you have a total of 3 pieces which should cost you only [$10 according to policy](http://www.greyhound.com/en/ticketsandtravel/baggageinformation.aspx).

As far as general attitude of people at the stations depends on the person you encounter and if someone want to give you a hard time you will certainly get it.

As far as police stops are concerned.  Question is you which direction your bus is going to even be an issue but again.  If she has your parents permission letter there shouldn't be any issue.

**EDIT**

Express Reservation as far as I can tell is reservation for [Greyhound Express](http://www.greyhound.com/Express/Default.aspx) with all the amenities.

Answer (score 1):

Just to respond to a few of your concerns...

- Most Greyhound stations are relatively small, so finding your way around is not that hard. If the doors/gates are not clearly marked, ask! In the smaller stations, (which may be gas stations or truck stops) the person behind the counter is usually a local expert on Greyhound and often more helpful than the actual Greyhound personnel.
- Print at home tickets are usually easier to use than buying tickets at the station. I've done both, and have never run into problems when using my non-standard photo ID (I've never travelled with a minor though, so that may be different).
- 'Difficult' personnel at the stations... Yes, sometimes, but usually only if you are obviously not paying attention to the announcements (overhead announcements or posted announcements). If you try to buck the system, Greyhound is not known to be sympathetic or nice. However, if you are polite and patient when making a request, the people you meet will usually be nice in return, or at least relatively civil!
- **This advice holds no matter where or how you are traveling**. Walk confidently. Keep your eyes and ears open. If your gut says it isn't safe, it probably isn't. And last but certainly not least, Enjoy the journey!